# Why are my HTML form images being uploaded twice in my PHP script?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Am taking images from HTML forms with multple attributes then renaming it and sending it into a folder using php

everything works but each images selected is uploaded douple in the location folder. this is my code

php

```
 $file_array = $_FILES['image'];
    $file_count = count($file_array['name']);

    // Loop through the uploaded files
    for($i=0;$i<$file_count;$i++){
        $file_name = $file_array['name'][$i];
        $file_tmp = $file_array['tmp_name'][$i];
        $file_type = $file_array['type'][$i];

        // Get the file extension
        $file_ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        // Generate a new file name using a unique ID and the file extension
        $new_file_name = uniqid().'.'.$file_ext;

        // Move the uploaded file to the desired directory with the new file name
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, 'uploads/'.$new_file_name);

        echo "File ".$file_name." has been renamed to ".$new_file_name." and uploaded to the server.<br>";
    }
```

ajax

```
$("#product_form").submit(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        // alert("Are you sure you want to Upload")
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'assets/php/process.php',
                            method: 'post',
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            cache: false,
                            data: new FormData(this),
                            success: function(response) {
                                console.log(response);

                            }
   });
                    });
```

Comment: Please show the source code of the html form here.